# Camel FTP: directory name with umlaut

Tags: encoding, ftp, apache-camel

I'm working with camel-ftp and I have problems with German umlauts (e.g. Ö) in the directory name to connect to the FTP-Server. I can't rename this directory because it's a working directory of the company.

I use camel.version: 2.18.1 and camel-ftp.version: 2.18.1.

I configured following route (in the route I defined the directory which contains the umlaut with the unicode character \u00d6 for Ö):

```
from(ftp://user@hostname:21/etc/\u00d6ffentlicherOrdner/test?password=pwd).routeId("kurse").to(...)
```

Error message:

```
Consumer FtpConsumer[ftp://user@hostname:21/etc//0ï¿½ffentlicherOrdner/test?password=xxxxxx] 
failed polling endpoint: ftp://ftp://user@hostname:21/etc/0ï¿½ffentlicherOrdner/test?password=xxxxxx. 
Will try again at next poll. 
Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - 
File operation failed: 550 ï¿½ffentlicherOrdner: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

When I extend the route with the following parameters:

```
&ftpClient.controlEncoding=ISO-8859-15    
&charset=ISO-8859-15    
&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true
```

Then I get the output that everything seems fine, because I didn't get any error message:

```
Route: kurse started and consuming from: ftp://user@hostname:21/etc/ÖffentlicherOrdner/test?charset=ISO-8859-1&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true&ftpClient.controlEncoding=ISO-8859-1&password=xxxxxx
```

But now no files are polled. I have some files in test directory but when i start the process it isn't pushing the files to the endpoint.

I don't understand why it is not consuming the files? Maybe the encoding is still wrong?

**EDIT:**

I was so fixed concerning the encoding that I missed to check the FTP properties.

The solution of my problem was to set the passiveMode:

```
&passiveMode=true
```

Comment: Maybe you can try, as a test, with recursive=true and then configure the starting directory to be the parent of that german directory, and then see if it can traverse down that folder and download the files, eg so you avoid configuring a starting directory with the german character.

Comment: I was so fixed conserning the encoding, that I missed to check the FTP properties. The solution of my problem was to set the passiveMode.