# Camel ftps filename with UK pound in camelFileName header as Â£

Tags: java, apache-camel, special-characters, filenames, camel-ftp

I am using the ftps camel component with camel version 2.22.0. The ftp server is on Linux.

https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftps-component.html

The filename has special characters which are being encoded using the java.net.URLEncoder to UTF-8. I am using the camelFileName header to encode the filename.

Special characters such as single quotes, double quotes, braces are being encoded, however when the filename has an UK pound sign £, the camel header camelFileName is populated with two special characters, Â£, both are being encoded. Can someone explain why this is?

Example:

```
Filename: testfile£.csv,
camelFileName header: testfileÂ£.csv,
encoded filename: testfile%C3%82%C2%A3.csv

String fileName = (String) message.getHeader(CAMEL_FILENAME);

String encodedFileName = Utils.encodeValue(fileName);

private String encodeValue(String value) {
    return URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Encoding problem may produce strange characters**

When convert [from utf-8 to iso-8859-1](http://string-functions.com/encodingtable.aspx?encoding=65001&decoding=28591) or [from utf-8 to windows-1252](http://string-functions.com/encodingtable.aspx?encoding=65001&decoding=1252), UK pound sign `£` will convert to `Â£`.

Probably the server side OS store the filename as UTF-8 and client side OS use iso-8859-1/windows-1252 as default language. This cause the filename change due to the encoding problem.

Combine [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805510/camel-ftp-directory-name-with-umlaut) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535925/filename-encoding-in-apache-commons-net-ftpclient), setting `ftpClient.controlEncoding` to `UTF-8` might help on your case.